# How can I take logarithms of Ints in Haskell and make them Ints again?

Tags: haskell, math

It appears I can do this in GHCi:

```hs
Prelude> (round . log) 9
2
```

But not this?

```hs
Prelude> x = 9 :: Int
Prelude> (round . log) x

<interactive>:22:2: error:
    • Could not deduce (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of ‘round’
      from the context: Integral c
        bound by the inferred type of it :: Integral c => c
        at <interactive>:22:1-15
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘round’
      In the expression: round . log
      In the expression: (round . log) x

<interactive>:22:10: error:
    • Could not deduce (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘log’
      from the context: Integral c
        bound by the inferred type of it :: Integral c => c
        at <interactive>:22:1-15
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘log’
      In the expression: round . log
      In the expression: (round . log) x
```

I know there are lots of types for numbers, but this one is confusing me. How can I write a function `roundedLog :: Int -> Int`?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the type of the expression. You're already using GHCi. Instead of evaluating the expression, ask GHCi about its type:

```
Prelude> :t (round . log) 9
(round . log) 9 :: Integral c => c
```

This, however, only tells you about the type of the result. It doesn't tell you which type it inferred that `9` was. Instead, ask GHCi about the type of the composed function:

```
Prelude> :t (round . log)
(round . log) :: (RealFrac a, Integral c, Floating a) => a -> c
```

That tells you that the input type `a` must be an instance of both `RealFrac` and `Floating`. That's how you could type a function that does what you want.

Which concrete types are candidates?

Again, you can ask GHCi:

```
Prelude> :info RealFrac
class (Real a, Fractional a) => RealFrac a where
  properFraction :: Integral b => a -> (b, a)
  truncate :: Integral b => a -> b
  round :: Integral b => a -> b
  ceiling :: Integral b => a -> b
  floor :: Integral b => a -> b
  {-# MINIMAL properFraction #-}
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
instance RealFrac Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
instance RealFrac Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
```

There are two candidate instances: `Float` and `Double`. It turns that these are also `Floating` instances.

So, to repeat your experiment, you could type `x` as either `Float` or `Double`. Here's your experiment with `x` typed as `Double`:

```
Prelude> x = 9 :: Double
Prelude> (round . log) x
2
```

If you're writing a reusable function, however, it'd be more flexible if you leave it open so that it might accept any `RealFrac` and `Floating` instance.

If in doubt, first write the function *without* a type declaration. Once it works like you want it to work, use `:t` in GHCi to see what the inferred type is. You can then (optionally) add that type signature to the function declaration. Haskell doesn't require this (unless you're adding certain language extensions), but it's considered good practice, at least for exported functions.

If you truly want to write a function with the type `Int -> Int`, you'll have to convert the input `Int` as [Z-Y.L describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64964840/126014).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can check the types of `9` and `log` in GHCi by typing:

```hs
ghci> :t 9
9 :: Num a => a

ghci> :t log
log :: Floating a => a -> a
```

As you can see, in the code `(round . log) 9`, `9` belongs to the typeclass `Num`, and `log` needs a parameter that belongs to the typeclass `Floating`. Since `Floating` is a sub-typeclass of `Num`, GHCi or GHC can transform the type of `9` from `Num a` to `Floating a` automatically (actually by `fromInteger`), which is called *type inference*. Therefore, when you type `(round . log) 9· directly in the prompt, without specifying any type information, GHCi or GHC do all the type-inference works for you automatically.

In contrast, if you specify the type of `9` as `Int`, then `x` passed in to `log` doesn't match the type required by `log`, since the parameter needs to be `Floating a`, while `Int` is not an instance of the typeclass `Floating`. The solution is to transform the type manually by using `fromIntegral`:

```hs
ghci> x = 9 :: Int

ghci> (round . log . fromIntegral) x
2
```